# In Ubuntu 16.4, Ubuntu Software used to work fine now it fails to start giving an internal error

Tags: software-center

In Ubuntu 16.4, Ubuntu Software used to work fine now it fails to start. It gives a system internal error.
I have installed the older Software Center which works fine. But I would still like to get Ubuntu software working. Would removing and reinstalling help?

Comment: Can you please take a screenshot of the error?  Also, have you tried running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` from the terminal?

Comment: Can you also run the command `ubuntu-software` and give us the Terminal output please?